# How to debug stored procedures in Sybase ASE?

Tags: debugging, stored-procedures, sap-ase

Is there a good tool from either Sybase or elsewhere that will enable me to debug stored procedures in Sybase ASE? I need to be able to set breakpoints & watchpoints.

Previously, in Sybase ASA (not ASE), I used Sybase Central to do this. There is a plugin for ASE, but I doubt it will let me debug procedures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sybase ASE comes with a command line debugger called sqldbgr.  Not the most user friendly option, but it does work.  You can find documentation for this in the Utility Guide.

Alternatively Embarcadero produces a [SQL debugger](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/debugger).

Comment: The above link to the Embarcadero site is now broken.

Comment: Also Aqua Data Studio from Aqua Fold has SQL debuggers for [Sybase ASE](http://www.aquafold.com/aquadatastudio/sybase_sql_debugger.html)  and others

Comment: hello kindly update "SQL debugger." link. above one is expired.

Comment: Is there option in aqua data studio to run queries during debugging, and using temp tables and variables?

Comment: yes! during a breakpoint you can run queries using the same connection/spid

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at Sybase Workspace. It's a database tool to support Sybase database servers. It comes with debug facility.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall the Embarcadero SQL Debugger works for debugging Stored Procs in ASE.  I think it is a plugin for DBArtsian. Check out their web site to get more.

Cheers,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

CAST SQL Builder (by castsoftware.com) has a debugger where you can do all the common tasks, step into, over, watch variables, select from temporary tables and so on. It's great tool, unfortunately, for home use, it costs.

Answer (score 0):

Allethrin has provided the full answer.

But for this:
*Alas, I need to debug some existing procedures to determine if they will break when new functionality is implemented elsewhere in the system*
You certainly do not need a stored procedure debugger.  Just read the stored procedure code.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL editor QweryBuilder from Werysoft has a debugger for Sybase ASE: http://www.werysoft.com/

Answer (score 0):

Aqua Data Studio from Aqua Fold has SQL debuggers for [Sybase ASE](http://www.aquafold.com/aquadatastudio/sybase_sql_debugger.html) and others (Oracle, DB2 LUW, and SQL Server).

Also, Sybase ASE ships with a command line sp debugger called sqldbgr.

Answer (score -1):

Use Oracle SQL Developer. I'm presently working through a JDBC connection to a Sybase ASE database using this tool. This seems to be Eclipse-based, but is quite responsive and allows you to view source code for functions and procs too. There is also a debugger available.

To create a new Sybase connection, on the "New / Select Database Connection" window, just click on the Sybase tab, enter your hostname/port/username/password, choose a database to access, and that's it.

And this software is free of charge! One thing I love about Oracle is that they give away so many good stuff for free (think JDeveloper IDE for ADF, JRockit JVM and Mission Control, and this tool).

http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html

Comment: Apologies. Debugger in Oracle SQL Developer works only for Oracle PL/SQL, not Sybase.

Comment: Update this in the answer as PS: . I wasted some time by not reading the above comment. Thanks though.